# (SQL) Update row which is included null foreign key error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database project. When i try to update row which is included null foreign key it gives me `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("archaelogy"."artifact", CONSTRAINT "location" FOREIGN KEY ("location_id") REFERENCES "location" ("location_id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE SET NULL` error. I can add a row which is included null foreign key but can't update it.

This is my php code :

```
function editArtifact($editData){
$query = "UPDATE artifact SET worker_id=?, image=?, period=?,location_id=?, coordinate_x=?, coordinate_y=?, type=?, comment=?) WHERE artifact_id=?";
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ibsiddsss", $editData['worker_id'],$editData['image'],$editData['period'],$editData['location_id'],$editData['coordinate_x'],$editData['coordinate_y'],$editData['type'],$editData['comment'],$editData['artifact_id']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo json_encode(array("editStatus"=>array('success'=>true)));
}else{
  echo json_encode(array("editStatus"=>array('success'=>false)));
}

$stmt->close();
```

}

and this is my post:

```
artifact_id=qw & worker_id=1 & image=null & period=null & location_id=null & coordinate_x=null & coordinate_y=null & type=null & comment=null
```

Database design:

[image: database design]

I don't understand that, I can insert a null column but can't update it.

Comment: `location` table is your primary table. Correct? If yes location table `location_id` and artifact `location_id` should be same type while you update.

Comment: @elumalai_kp location table has location_id as primary key and artifact table has location_id too as foreign key referenced by location table. location_ids' type are int[11].

Comment: Can you show the table structure of location and artifact table?

Comment: without looking at table structure it is not possible to tell exact reason

Comment: Database design added. I hope this will help you to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, i fixed the problem. Problem was on my php code. I was trying to determine null values with isset construct. When i try to determine null with '===', problem has fixed.

Fixed php code:

```
<?php
require_once "DbOperations.php";
$response=array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   if (isset($_POST['artifact_id'])) {

$editData;
if($_POST['artifact_id']!=='null'){
  $editData['artifact_id']=$_POST['artifact_id'];
  if($_POST['worker_id']!=='null'){
    $editData['worker_id']=$_POST['worker_id'];
  }else{
    $editData['worker_id']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['image']!=='null'){
    $editData['image']=$_POST['image'];
  }else{
    $editData['image']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['period']!=='null'){
    $editData['period']=$_POST['period'];
  }else{
    $editData['period']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['location_id']!=='null'){
    $editData['location_id']=$_POST['location_id'];
  }else{
    $editData['location_id']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['coordinate_x']!=='null'){
    $editData['coordinate_x']=$_POST['coordinate_x'];
  }else{
    $editData['coordinate_x']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['coordinate_y']!=='null'){
    $editData['coordinate_y']=$_POST['coordinate_y'];
  }else{
    $editData['coordinate_y']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['type']!=='null'){
    $editData['type']=$_POST['type'];
  }else{
    $editData['type']=null;
  }
  if($_POST['comment']!=='null'){
    $editData['comment']=$_POST['comment'];
  }else{
    $editData['comment']=null;
  }

    $db = new DbOperations();
    $db->editArtifact($editData);
  }
  }else{
       $response['error']=true;
       json_encode($response);
    }
  }
?>
```

thanks everybody for trying to fix problem. I am posting data from an android app. I don't know why it is posting null string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to update `artifact` a `location_id` value that doesn't exist in `location` table. Also check your post parameter `location_id=null`. There may not be a `location_id` as null in your `location` table. Hope this helps!

Your `location_id` in `artifact` table should allow `NULL` values.

Note: To utilize the SET NULL rule for update/delete operations the foreign key column should allow NULL values otherwise the SET NULL specification would fail by generating an error message.

Comment: location table's primary key is location_id so i can't add a null location_id to this table. I just want to update row to artifact table which is included null location_id as foreign_key.